# Why doesn't my program work without the help of Visual Studio?

Tags: vb.net

I am really confused! My program doesn't work if I don't have Visual Studio here in my PC. To test it I have uninstalled Visual Studio. But my program doesn't work though Flash Player is present there (I have used Flash animation in the first form).

To be more sure about it I have installed Flash. But it's not working! That means the Flash animation file (.swf) is not making a problem! It needs support from Visual Studio to start. Doesn't it mean that some files are not attached with a setup file as a result it needs Visual Studio to run? Let me tell you how I create a setup file of my program.

1. Project > WindowsApplication1 properties > Compile > Advance compile option > Target CPU : AnyCPU Target framework(all configurations): .NET Framework 3.5 > OK
2. File > Add > New Project > Other Project Types > Setup and Deployment > Setup Project > OK
3. Setup > Properties > Prerequisites > Select Create setup program to install prerequisite components & Windows Installer 3.1 & .NET Framework 3.5 & Download prerequisites from the same location as my application > OK > Apply > OK
4. Setup > View > File system >  Select Application folder of File System on Target Machine > Add > Project output > Primary output > Configuration > Active > OK > Message will be shown "Microsoft Visual Studio >  "The following files may have dependencies that cannot be determined automatically. Please confirm that all dependencies have been added to the project. d:\windows\speech\vtext.dll d:\windows\system32\macromed\flash\flash10i.ocx d:\windows\system32msadodc.ocx d:\windows\system32mshflxgd.ocx > OK
5. Application Folder will get files
6. Application Folder > Add > FileWindowsApplication1 > bin > Debug > Animation.swf > Open
7. Application Folder will get Animation.swf file
8. Application Folder > Add > FileWindowsApplication1 > bin > Debug > CrystalReport1 CrystalReport2 CrystalReport3 CrystalReport4 CrystalReport5 CrystalReport6 > Open
9. Application Folder will get CrystalReport1 2 3 4 5 & 6 files
10. Application Folder > Select Primary output from SUIMT(Active) > Create shortcut to Primary output from SUIMT (Active)
11. Application Folder >  Select that shortcut file & bring it to User`s desktop Folder
12. User`s Programs Menu > Create Folder(Use program`s name as folder`s name)
13. Application Folder >  Create another shortcut & bring it to User`s Programs Menu > Folder(program`s name as folder`s name)
14. Build > Build Solution
15. Build > Build Setup

When I click on the icon of my program it shows the error message

> WindowsApplication1 has encountered a problem and needs to close we are sorry for the inconvenience
>
> Error signature EventType : clr20r3 P1 : windowsapplication1.exe P2 : 1.0.0.0 P3 : 4ca21bfa P4 : system.windows.forms P5 : 2.0.0.0 P6 : 471ebf68 P7 : 3dad P8: 97 P9 : systemio.filenotfoundexception

Reporting details: This error report includes information regarding the condition of `WindowsApplication1`. When the problem occurred the operating system version and computer hardware is use; your Digital Product ID, which could be used to identify your license; and the Internet Protocol(IP) anddress of your computer.

Comment: Care to post the error message?

Comment: You've not explained in what way your program fails to run.  That information would be vital to form any kind of answer.

Comment: When I click on the icon of my program it shows error message that "WindowsApplication1 has encountered a problem and needs to close we are sorry for the inconvenience".

Comment: Error signature EventType : clr20r3 P1 : windowsapplication1.exe P2 : 1.0.0.0 P3 : 4ca21bfa P4 : system.windows.forms P5 : 2.0.0.0 P6 : 471ebf68 P7 : 3dad P8: 97 P9 : systemio.filenotfoundexception

Comment: Reporting details : This error report includes : information regarding the condition of WindowsApplication1 when the problem occurred the operating system version and computer hardware is use; your Digital Product ID, which could be used to identify your license; and the Internet Protocol(IP) anddress of your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I see mention of Crystal Reports files but no mention of the Crystal Reports prerequisite package included in the installation. That would be my guess without seeing the error message.

Comment: How should I add Crystal Report prerequisite package? It shows error message that "WindowsApplication1 has encountered a problem and needs to close we are sorry for the inconvenience" It has two links & two buttons. From what data does this error report contain link I have got following information:

Comment: Error signature 

EventType : clr20r3  P1 : windowsapplication1.exe  P2 : 1.0.0.0
P3 : 4ca21bfa  P4 : system.windows.forms  P5 : 2.0.0.0  P6 : 471ebf68
P7 : 3dad P8: 97  P9 : systemio.filenotfoundexception

Reporting details :

This error report includes : information regarding the condition of WindowsApplication1 when the problem occurred the operating system version and computer hardware is use; your Digital Product ID, which could be used to identify your license; and the Internet Protocol(IP) anddress of your computer.

Comment: I have read it that to get rid of crystal report`s problem I have to add merge module. I have tried to find it out but I didnt get it. As I result I have installed here in my windows CRRedist2005_x86 (crystal report msi file to solve this problem) but I cant run my program because of that error so I cant tell it that it works or not.

Comment: I see "systemio.filenotfoundexception" in there, where is that being thrown?

Comment: I have used "Imports System" and "Imports System.IO" there in my first form. Is it making problem? Do you want me to remove those lines from my code?